# Can a Human use the Disguise Self spell to appear like a Grung?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, disguise, human, grung

Can a Human use the *Disguise Self* spell to appear like a Grung?

I want to pretend I'm the grung goddess Nangnang, and I thought of using *Disguise Self* to make that illusion. My party will support me with *Daylight*, *Minor Illusion*, yelling Grung phrases into a horn that amplifies and distorts them, *Fog Cloud* and a Griffon for a stylish landing, and an invisible Imp touching the Grung King as I pretend to touch him from a distance (to avoid physical inspection).

The [*Disguise Self*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self) spell description states:

> You make yourself look different until the spell ends. You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller and can appear thin, fat, or in between. You can’t change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs. Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you.

Now, Grungs are fairly different from regular humans, but they are still humanoid, have similar limbs, etc. I would become a very big Grung, but that is to be expected - I'm a damn Goddess! Is this plan feasible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, that'll work. "The extent of the illusion is up to you" as long as you keep the same number and arrangement of limbs, but Grung have a generic humanoid shape with 2 arms, 2 legs and a head.

As long as your target has two legs, two arms, a torso and a head Disguise Self will work. At worst you'll be a bit larger or smaller than your intended target, but the spell doesn't even state you need to look like any existing species of creature, so you can make up all sorts of stuff, including a frog-goddess.